# How to integrate phpBB with Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, web, symfony-1.4, forum, phpbb

I'm developing a web application which have a online forum with it. I'm going to use Sysmfony 1.4 as my php framework for the application.

Since the forum is the main feature of my web application it is very important to have a well design forum for the application. For the forum I found that phpBB is a great solution so I'm willing to integrate phpBB with symfonny. I went through the following discussion  [What is the best forum plug-in solution for the Symfony framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666110/what-is-the-best-forum-plug-in-solution-for-the-symfony-framework) but didn't help much for the task.

Is it possible to integrate phpBB with Symfony?

If so please can someone help me on that.

Regards,
Thilanka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use [prestaForumConnectorPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/prestaForumConnectorPlugin) that allows to connect sfGuard (Propel or Doctrine versions) to phpBB3.